# Ajax request cross domain json data and display?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function to get JSON data from another domain, but I don't know what is wrong with it. It never fires the success function and and no errors are returned.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://other-domain.com/sample/Json.aspx",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    type: 'get',
    crossDomain: true,
    jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
    success: function() {
        alert('abc'); //when success take json data string but i din get in here
    }
});
```

Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Comment: Questions should be asked using coherent sentences that contain full words and capital letters... what makes you think we're going to answer a question that you couldn't be bothered to spend more than 5 seconds writing?

Comment: No reason to downvote this - it's a legitimate question.

Comment: @Matt maybe English isn't his first language?

Comment: How do you know no errors are returned? Why don't you have an error handler? Are you expecting to use CORS or JSONP for this?

Comment: Your script is not outtputting JSON-P. It is redirecting through an account suspected page and splurging out an advertising page in HTML. (Or did you mean to use `example.com`?)

Comment: What does "when success take json data string but i din get in here" mean?

Comment: (While I haven't downvoted this, I'm surprised that so many people have up-voted this as "useful and clear")

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$.get('http://other-domain.com/sample/Json.aspx', function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

You should get an alert with a json string (which is actually a string), than use `jQuery.parseJSON(data)` on it and you'll get a JSON object to work on.

If this doesn't work, maybe you need to check your get parameters.

Edit:

I just tried to set up this page right now:

```
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?',function(data){

                alert(data.title);

            });

        });

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    ... WHATEVER ...        

</body>
```

and it works just fine, it's alerting the first title element in the data object.

Comment: A JSON-P request shouldn't give you a JSON string. It should give you a JavaScript object. Why should using this syntax give different results to the direct `$.ajax` call?

Comment: I'm not saying it will work better, he says he needs to get some JSON stuff, he may try $.getJSON() too. It's simpler and with less stuff to set.

Comment: $.getJSON() got a way to get cross domain data,but is using YQL method.totaly confuse that.

Comment: I used $.getJSON at university and works for sure cross domain... I rmember I had to add "&format=json&jsoncallback=?" in the get URL to make it work http://docs.jquery.com/Getjson

Comment: yup i tried that,but fail to request url.I am sure my url is correct.

Comment: have you tried to write the URL in your brawser and see what it displays?